# Collation Conflict error working on local sql not on server hosting database

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have t-sql which is working fine on the local sql server if I run the same t-sql on the remote sql server hosting the database ginving the error

I tried a lot of changes but nothing works for me finally I decide to write on Stack Exchange.

I cretaed my local database with the script from the server so I hope no chance if their is change in any datatypes as my query is giving me correct result.

Here is my t-sql

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TempAppliedData') IS NOT NULL  
  BEGIN  
        DROP TABLE #TempAppliedData  
  END  

Create Table #TempAppliedData(
--RecordNo [int],
IdNo1 [nvarchar](50) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT,
--Name [nvarchar](50),
AYear2011 [char](3) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT,
AYear2012 [char](3) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT,
AYear20121 [char](3) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT, 
AYear2013 [char](3) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT,
AYear20131 [char](3) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
);


insert into #TempAppliedData (IdNo1) select distinct  IdNo from AppliedData


update #TempAppliedData 
set 
AYear2011=(select CASE WHEN COUNT(A.Year2011)=0 then 'No' else 'YES' end FROM AppliedData A WHERE Year2011='Yes' and IdNo1=IdNo) ;


update #TempAppliedData 
set 
AYear2012=(select CASE WHEN COUNT(A.Year2012)=0 then 'No' else 'YES' end FROM AppliedData A WHERE ApplnYear <=20131 AND Year2012='Yes' and IdNo1=IdNo)


update #TempAppliedData 
set 
AYear20121=(Select CASE WHEN COUNT(A.Year20121)=0 then 'No' else 'YES' end FROM AppliedData A WHERE ApplnYear <=20131 AND Year20121='Yes' and IdNo1=IdNo)



update #TempAppliedData 
set 
AYear2013=(Select CASE WHEN COUNT(A.Year2013)=0 then 'No' else 'YES' end FROM AppliedData A WHERE ApplnYear <=20131  AND Year2013='Yes' and IdNo1=IdNo)


update #TempAppliedData 
set 
AYear20131=(Select CASE WHEN COUNT(A.Year20131)=0 then 'No' else 'YES' end FROM AppliedData A WHERE ApplnYear <=20131  AND Year20131='Yes' and IdNo1=IdNo)




Select * from #TempAppliedData;

--select distinct IdNo from AppliedData
```

Its producing error is as below:

```
Msg 468, Level 16, State 9, Line 28
Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS" and "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" in the equal to operation.
Msg 468, Level 16, State 9, Line 40
Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS" and "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" in the equal to operation.
Msg 468, Level 16, State 9, Line 53
Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS" and "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" in the equal to operation.
Msg 468, Level 16, State 9, Line 66
Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS" and "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" in the equal to operation.
Msg 468, Level 16, State 9, Line 79
Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS" and "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" in the equal to operation.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Create Table #TempAppliedData(
 IdNo1 [nvarchar](50) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT,
```

Here you are creating column which has the default collation of your hosting `tempdb`. Apparently your own database uses a CI collation, while the hosting service is deployed with a CS collation.

Use an explicit collation in your scripts, rather than rely on the existing deployment collation. Ideally you should always develop under identical settings as you will deploy. ansyou

Answer (score 0):

Just add after value where you have an error  `COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS`

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have different collation on the columns IdNo1 and IdNo (you should use alias so people know where columns belong)

```
update B 
set AYear2011 =
case when exists (
select 1
FROM AppliedData A 
WHERE A.Year2011='Yes' and B.IdNo1=A.IdNo collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS) 
) then 'Yes' else 'No' End
-- or this: collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
from #TempAppliedData B
```

Notice the big change, otherwise the value of AYear2011 will never be 'No'